# Can't run jupyter notebook in network drive (Windows)

Tags: python, jupyter

I'm trying to open a jupyter notebook in a network drive using an Anaconda prompt but the prompt won't let me cd into the network drive, presumably because it is not local? Is there a way to do it?

Comment: My terminal won't let me cd into the network drive either. I run this                     `C:\Users\Melanie>cd Z:\Wilson Lab\Mel`                                                                       and get the following `C:\Users\Melanie`. It just ignores my command

Comment: you might need the `/d` argument, like `cd /d "Z:\Wilson Lab\Mel"`

Comment: that worked! Please post it as the answer so that I can vote for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When changing drives in a windows command prompt (cmd.exe) you need to use the `/d` argument:

> Syntax
>         CD [/D] [drive:][path]
>         CD [..]
>
> Key    /D : change the current DRIVE in addition to changing folder.

In your case:
`cd /d "Z:\Wilson Lab\Mel"`.

See [here](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html) for more info.

By the way, when using powershell this is not necessary.